# How to capture image & save into the Gallery with Ionic Framework

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

Using ionic framework how would I capture an image and save it to the gallery?

I tried several options but it doesn't work well with Marshmallow version of Android.

Comment: Which plugin you are using for camera ?

Comment: cordova-plugin-camera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cordova-plugin-camera (For capturing Image)
cordova-plugin-file-transfer (For uploading)
cordova-plugin-file (For accessing device’s files and directories )
```

Use these plugin as per your requirement . http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/camera/

Afterwards If you are facing imgae not showing problem , Than use this

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-refresh-gallery
```

Comment: not worked with Marshmallow

Comment: updated my answer . Go for it :)

Comment: where? @Ujjwal Kaushik

Comment: I have updated my answer .. use refresh gallery plugin

Answer (score 1):

Add cordova-plugin-camera plugin

Command : *ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-camera*

HTML

```
   <span class="button" ng-click = captureImage();> Capture </span>
```

Ref:
  http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/camera/

JS

```
.controller('cameraCtrl', function($scope,$cordovaCamera) {
    $scope.captureImage = function() {
        var options = {
            quality: 100,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
            sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
            allowEdit: false,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
            saveToPhotoAlbum: true
        };

    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
        $scope.imgURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    }, function(err) {
        console.log("An error Occured");
    });
    }

});
```

Comment: It takes photo from camera but doesn't showed up in Gallery specially for Android 6

Comment: Try installing the plugin directly from github and try still issue is there `cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera`

Comment: is it working for other android version??

Comment: yes it does works for another versions